# Why do the same characters take different space in different browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, unicode, cross-browser

Why are on Chrome and FF the characters with the green background take more space?
On Internet Explorer all characters taking the same space (height)

I made a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xuqa3a0f/

```html
  <div style="background: yellow; float: left">↕</div>
  <div style="background: Chartreuse; float: left">▴</div>
  <div style="background: yellow; float: left">A</div>
  <div style="background: yellow; float: left">B</div>
  <div style="background: yellow; float: left">C</div>
  <div style="background: yellow; float: left">1</div>
  <div style="background: yellow; float: left">2</div>
  <div style="background: yellow; float: left">3</div>
  <div style="background: yellow; float: left">↔</div>
  <div style="background: Chartreuse; float: left">↖</div>
```

thx for any answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Special characters in HTML can use different fonts and these can have different line-height.

It is talked in great length here: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html

But to fix it you have to use a common line height.

It looks fine if i use the following css in your example:

```
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background: chartreuse;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

So i would say it is not a bug, but the browser interprets the characters differently.

Comment: Thx for your answer. It didn't solve my problem. I have a table structure and need this structure.

It looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vepm87Ly/

I need equal heights of every line, but the first line is higher, because of the space consumption of the special character.

I don't want to use pixel heights if it is possible.

Comment: I did change my answer because i did find some new info. I do not think there is solution without using line-height to fix it. If you dont want to use pixel-height, you could also set your line-height with em or pt, like: line-height: 1.5pt;

Comment: Thx for your answers and explanations.